# Multiple 'values' in json data field to pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some simple json files, short example below:

```
{"day": "Monday", "location": [51.5, -0.2]}
```

When I read them into a pandas dataframe I seem to get 2 rows, one with the lat value and one with the long value. How do I get it to read both of those values?

I want to have:

```
|1|Monday|51.5,-0.2|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the dictionary in a list:

```
l = [{"day": "Monday", "location": [51.5, -0.2]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

If you want the index to start with 1:

```
df.index += 1
```

Output:

```
      day      location
1  Monday  [51.5, -0.2]
```